# Trying to figure out to solve the below Fibonacci Sequence, need to validate with the results I have got

Tags: recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers, recursive-algorithms

> Define the New Fibonacci sequence (denoted NF) to have the same
> recursive definition for n greater or equal than 2 as the Fibonacci
> sequence, except where the base cases are now changed to NF0 equals 2
> and NF1 equals 5. Find the value of NF3.

I am a programmer and I am trying to derive this, however I am not sure whether I am right or wrong with the answer I am getting which is 12, hence looking out to validate my answer with. Thank you in advance

Comment: NF3= NF2+NF1=(NF1+NF0)+NF1=5+2+5=12.

Comment: Thank you Conifold for the detailed response, Appreciate it!

Comment: You only need $2+5=7$ and $5+7=12$ to calculate $NF_3$